# Where to change setting like `offline-apps.allow...` in firefox?

Tags: firefox, microsoft-outlook

I'm trying to change `offline-apps.allow_by_default;true` to `offline-apps.allow_by_default;false` in order to prevent **harpjs** and **outlook** from storing content on my PC.  Can someone tell me where I change this?

Even though I've expressly said "do not store data on my PC without my knowledge", they're doing it anyway.

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1014708

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox configuration address lists a ton of configurable items.

```
about:config
```

You can toggle the value there.